Delete Kubernetes namespace with delay
I have the following issue. We need to implement a command which deletes a Kubernetes namespace but with some delay of 1 hour. I tried with this one but it's not working:
kubectl delete ns $NAMESPACE --grace-period=3600

Do you have any ideas or recommendations how it could be done?

Forced deletions can be potentially disruptive for some workloads and their Pods.So we have grace-period - the time that Kubernetes wait before force delete the resources. By default it set to 30 seconds, but you can specify it with this flag --grace-period. Deleting process start at the moment you run the command.
For you purposes you can use bash script, or, in my view it's more graceful way, Kubernetes Job
kube-job.yaml:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: delete-namespace-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: delete-namespace
        image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
        - |
          sleep 3600;
          kubectl delete ns $NAMESPACE;
        env:
        - name: NAMESPACE
          value: "your-namespace"
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4

and then apply it:
kubectl apply -f kube-job.yaml

